# Why is the inner stem of my pothos cutting bright pink?

Tags: houseplants, diagnosis

I have been propagating some golden pothos cuttings in water and I recently noticed that the 'inner stem' is pink? Is this normal? Or is this a fungal or viral infection?

[image]

Comment: I don't know about pothos specifically but a lot of plant material is naturally coloured pink or red, except for the chlorophyll on the outside which is green.

Comment: I have never seen a pothos stem that is pink like this. Usually they are white or a creamy colour

Comment: @kevinsky Would you toss it? I just fear it might be some fungus (like fusarium) and I don't want it to spread, but it also pains my heart to toss away cuttings that have just rooted and otherwise seem healthy.

Comment: I would pot it up when it roots, but not in the same pot as any other plants, just in case